# redis expireAt not getting expired in server

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to auto expire the key in redis

```
when=10
unit='seconds'
redisClient.expireat(key,moment().add(when,unit));
```

On redis cli
Keys *
I can see the key I have set

```
> TTL 472962f1-10ad8-4c4d-bc5e-2e38b632f36
(integer) -1
> Exists 472962f1-10ad8-4c4d-bc5e-2e38b632f36
(integer) 1
```

and after 10 second it is not getting deleted !

I am using moment to get the time as I have to share the info in response that this key will not working after this.

```
var whenKeyExpire = moment().add(when,unit).format('MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss A')
```

Comment: this is resolved !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you're passing wrong value into the parameter of `expireat` function. For this function you have to check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-node#clientexpireatkey-unixtime-callback). In this function you have to pass unixtime. 
So for your scenario you can do something like this :

```
var when=10;
var unit="seconds";
redisClient.expireat(key, +new Date(moment().add(when,unit)), function (err, didSetExpiry){
   if(err){
      console.log("Error occured: " + err);
   } else {
      console.log("Redis Key Operation is successful");
   }
});
```

Hope that it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Ttl returns -1 if the key exists but has no associated expire.

I'm not famaliar with the node client, but I'm pretty sure that the expire time was not setted successfully.

Comment: I am using expire(no of sec) not expireAt(timestamp)....not sure if timestamp is correct input because when I give time stamp adding 10 sec (i.e 03-07-2017 12:56:10) and do TTL key it always show timestamp as integer which keep decreasing by seconds...which do not make sense. I was thinking it will be expire At the set timestamp..03-07-2017 12:56:10